# Send XML data from vb script to asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, vbscript

How I can send a XML data from a vb script to c# asp.net page ?

In my asp.net page, i have a button and its click event is in a vb script file.
When I am clicking the button, it is calling the vb script sub procedure.
But I want to send a XML data from that vb script sub method to asp.net page.

I don't want to do write any code in asp.net code bind and in my project, we are not using the session object.

Comment: Is your file big? How do you get that file in your VBScript file?

Comment: You may not get many answers - almost nobody uses VBScript in a web browser.

Comment: Consider instead the mainstream approach: [use JavaScript to POST your XML](http://stackoverflow.com/q/133925/1497596) to your ASP.NET page.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a POST request to your .aspx page.